# Complex numbers question

Tags: complex-numbers

Consider 3 nonzero complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3$ each satisfying $z^2=i \bar{z}$. We are supposed to find $z_1+z_2+z_3, z_1z_2z_3,  z_1z_2+z_2z_3+z_3z_1$.

The answers- $0$, purely imaginary , purely real respectively.

I have no idea how to proceed. I tried to use the expansion for $(a+b+c)^2$ for them, but I am not getting anywhere. Please help. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Taking the modulus gives $|z|^2=|i\overline{z}|=|z|$ hence $|z|=1$ since $z\not=0$. Multiplying both sides of the original equation by $z$ then gives:
$$z^3=i\overline{z}z=i|z|^2=i$$
that is $z^3-i=0$.

If you call the solutions of that $z_1$, $z_2$ and $z_3$, how can you find the numbers $z_1+z_2+z_3$, $z_1z_2z_3$ and $z_1z_2+z_2z_3+z_3z_1$ straight from the equation?

Comment: By writing the relations between coeffecients and roots......thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Try writing $z = a + ib$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and expand $z^2$ and $iz^-$. Then compare real and imaginary coefficients in the two expansions.